# Why is my app crashing on any API26 or lower?

Tags: java, android

My app works just fine whenever I run it on an API above 26, although whenever it is on any API lower than 26 or equal to 26, on a button click it just crashes, the button click attempts to Register/Login.
 It does not show any sort of error message on the logcat.

I have tried to check the @drawable-26 folder but I don't even have one.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

ProgressBar progressBar;
EditText email;
EditText password;
Button Register;
Button Login;

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_login );
    Objects.requireNonNull( getSupportActionBar() ).hide();

    progressBar = findViewById( R.id.login_progress );
    email = findViewById( R.id.email );
    password = findViewById( R.id.password );
    Register = findViewById( R.id.Register );
    Login = findViewById( R.id.Login );


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();





    Register.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, BottomActivity.class);
            startActivity( intent );
            progressBar.setVisibility( View.GONE );
             firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
                    .addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        email.setText( "" );
                        password.setText( "");
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, BottomActivity.class));

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this, Objects.requireNonNull( task.getException() ).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startActivity( new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class) );
                    }
                }
            } );



        }
    } );



    Login.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity( new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity2.class) );
        }
    });
}
 }
```

There you have my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.shrinkio">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.shrinkio.PersonListActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login2"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Messages"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_messages"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DashBoard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board" />

    <activity
        android:name=".BottomActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bottom" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

 </manifest>
```

I am currently getting these errors:

```
2019-05-02 20:56:41.847 15895-15895/com.example.shrinkio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shrinkio, PID: 15895
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6396)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:243)
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:211)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:466)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:410)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:368)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:339)
    at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:27)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

It is expected to register my app, through the firebase database, but the only thing I'm getting is an unexpected app crash.

Comment: Could you please share your stacktrace?

Comment: @ReneFerrari Exactly, that's what I don't understand, I get NO errors, no red sentences no nothing. It just crashes but my logcat is clean.

Comment: Read [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/295004) Double check the logcat output. Add in a `Log.d("MyApp","reached here")` if necessary to prove that the app you are getting the log for is the right one.

Comment: You need to disable the filters, set "Selected App Only" to "No Filters"

Comment: I have and it doesn’t show anything related to this

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192745/discussion-on-question-by-tomas-mota-why-is-my-app-crashing-on-any-api26-or-lowe).